# Segmentation Fault with DataFrame.to_json()

Tags: python, pandas, segmentation-fault

I have a Python code that works correctly with a file having 20 rows, but when I'm trying to send the same file with 60.000 records, it shows a "108936 Segmentation fault".

Is there any way to avoid this error, is this my machine? or there is a better way to do this? I'm using Pandas because I need to do a merge to the DataFrame sometimes (pd.merge()).

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

columns = [u'SalesOrderID', u'OrderDate', u'DueDate', u'ShipDate', u'SalesOrderNumber', u'Title', u'FirstName', u'MiddleName', u'LastName', u'Suffix', u'PhoneNumber', u'PhoneNumberType', u'EmailAddress', u'EmailPromotion', u'AddressType', u'AddressLine1', u'AddressLine2', u'City', u'StateProvinceName', u'PostalCode', u'CountryRegionName', u'SubTotal', u'TaxAmt', u'Freight', u'TotalDue', u'UnitPrice', u'ProductName', u'ProductSubcategory', u'ProductCategory']
data = pd.read_csv('../Uploads/TxtData.txt', header=0, names=columns, sep='\t')
data.to_json(orient='records')
```

Files used:

[Little File](http://pastebin.com/iYewEfTg)

[Big File](http://www.filedropper.com/txtdata)

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in DataFrame.to_json.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14256#issuecomment-249583941

The only current way to account for this is to us a default_handler for converting your objects to standard json datatypes. I don't know what is in txt.data and I don't know what could possibly be in a csv file that is exotic enough, but you need a default_handler.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue with Panda `Series` ( June 2022 ).  Same fix from `DataFrame` worked for `Series`:

```
#crash
df2 = df.groupby(['creationDate'])['creationDate'].count()
resp = df2.to_json()

#works
df2 = df.groupby(['creationDate'])['creationDate'].count()
resp = df2.to_json(orient='records', default_handler=str)
```